# Pre and post increment/decrement operators in C#

Tags: c#

In C#, does anybody know why the following will compile:

```
int i = 1;
++i;
i++;
```

but this will not compile?

```
int i = 1;
++i++;
```

(Compiler error: The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer.)

Comment: Its a legit question, why down him for it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you are running one of the operands on the result of the other, the result of a increment/decrement is a value - and you can not use increment/decrement on a value it has to be a variable that can be set.

Answer (score 10):

For the same reason you can't say

```
5++;
```

or

```
f(i)++;
```

A function returns a *value*, not a variable.  The increment operators also return values, but cannot be applied to values.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that ++i returns an integer value type, to which you then try to apply the ++ operator. Seeing as you can't write to a value type (think about 0++ and if that would make sense), the compiler will issue an error.

In other words, those statements are parsed as this sequence:

```
++i  (i = 2, returns 2)
2++  (nothing can happen here, because you can't write a value back into '2')
```

Answer (score -3):

My guess: to avoid such ugly and unnecessary constructs. Also it would use 2 operations (2x INC) instead of one (1x ADD 2).

Yes, i know ... "but i want to increase by two and i'm a l33t g33k!"

Well, don't be a geek and write something that doesn't look like an inadvertent mistake, like this:

```
i += 2;
```

Comment: That's a little harsh don't you think? He was only asking why it doesn't compile - a question about compiler design, not about code style.

Comment: That's being harsh. I found the question to be relevant and useful.